# Doubts about verify in array of totoloto the same number

Tags: java

I create a program for insert the numbers in input. but i want when writte the numbers in first verify if the number is the same that the save in array. If true alert the message this number are exits if not continue for insert the other number. but my problem when try the same number show the message and when go to input other number show-me the message of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. this is my code. And i can´t use the class the Math random only input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Totoloto \n");
    System.out.println("Insira a chave de 1 a 49 do Totoloto");

    int chave[] = new int[6];
    int numero = 0, contador = 0, i = 0;

    while (contador < 6) {
        System.out.println("Insira um número");
        numero = Ler.umInt();

        if (numero > 1 && numero <= 49) {
            for (int j = 0; j < chave.length; j++) {

                if (chave[j] != numero) {
                     chave[i] = numero;
                    i++;


                } else {
                    System.out.println("Os números inseridos já se encontram na chave");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("A chave deve conter números de 1 a 49 !!!");
            break;
        }
        contador++;
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("A chave do Totoloto é ");
    for (int j = 0; j < chave.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(chave[j]);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

}



##The Error##

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Index 6 out of bounds for length 6
at com.ubi.aula03.Aula03ex3.main(Aula03ex3.java:31)
```

Answer (score -1):

test this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Totoloto \n");
    System.out.println("Insira a chave de 1 a 49 do Totoloto");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int chave[] = new int[6];
    int numero = 0, contador = 0;

    mywhile:
    while (contador < 6) {
        System.out.print("Insira um número [" + contador + "]\t:");
        numero = reader.nextInt();

        if (numero >= 1 && numero <= 49) {

            for (int j = 0; j <= contador; j++) {

                if (chave[j] == numero) {

                    System.out.println("Os números inseridos já se encontram na chave");
                    continue mywhile;
                }
            }

            chave[contador] = numero;
            contador++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("A chave deve conter números de 1 a 49 !!!");
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < chave.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(chave[j]);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo but I have other problem when I change the code for the same of yours now when I entry in input the some number appear the message on else. "Os números inseridos já se encontram na chave" Insira um numero"

Comment: It's works now the problem is missing the break inside the if(chave[j]!=numero) {} Thanks a Lot

Comment: As I can see in your code, you are using an array, so Java initializes the full array with primitives default values, in this case the entire array contains 0 as value for all positions. Then, do not use 0 or a number you write previously, and it will be between 1-49.